# What does the asset Ace Pilot from Rats day 3 do?

Tags: payday-2

In the Rats mission, on day 3, there's an asset called "Ace Pilot" (which is a picture of a pilot smoking).

What happens once I buy it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the wiki](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Assets#Special_Assets):

> Ace Pilot (Rats Day 3): This asset allows special Ace Pilot Bile to
>   come and pick up the money closer to the bus. This helps players
>   having to struggle their way back to the (Alex) chopper ensure the
>   money quicker.

Comment: Any idea of which side of the bus ? Im guessing it will either on the right or left side of the bus, by the corner of the bridge.

Comment: @MarcelloGrechiLins It's random

Comment: @MarcelloGrechiLins I've played this mission several times with the Ace Pilot asset. The helicopter which picks up the bags is *always* at the upper left (northwest) of the bus, if in the bus driver's POV (lower right side, or southeast of the bus, if you're facing the front of the bus).